# Object Value not exporting to CSV file - Powershell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010

(Updated Title as I wrote it on the fly)

Got very stumped by this so far and relatively new to powershell.

I have the below script:

```
cd e:

Import-CSV e:\UserList.csv | Foreach-Object {Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity "$($_.account):\Kalender" -User Default} 

| select-object User,AccessRights | export-csv AccessList.csv
```

However whenever I run it I get the Object Type returned for the AccessRights parameter e.g.:

```
User,"AccessRights"
Default,"System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[Microsoft.Exchange.Management.StoreTasks.MailboxFolderAccessRight]"
Default,"System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[Microsoft.Exchange.Management.StoreTasks.MailboxFolderAccessRight]"
```

Anyone know how I can get the value out as it prints to powershell? e.g.:

```
User                                                        AccessRights
----                                                        ------------
Default                                                     {AvailabilityOnly}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure why it's behaving that way, but this seems to be a usable workaround:

```
Import-CSV e:\UserList.csv |
 Foreach-Object {
 Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity "$($_.account):\Kalender" -User Default
 } | select-object User,@{l='AccessRights';e={$_.AccessRights}} | 
 export-csv AccessList.csv
```

Comment: Works perfectly! I also managed to get this partially working by placing the select-object User, AccessRights within the Foreach-Object loop and then pushing to an Excel file using >> at the end of each loop. This didn't format it very nicely in the excel file as printed headers everytime.

Thanks for the help mjolinor!